# Options and value won't display in ember-select-guru

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying to use [ember-select-guru](https://netguru.github.io/ember-select-guru/#multiple) within my own component. The .hbs element looks like this. `{{ember-select-guru multiple=true value=values options=options onSelect=(action "onSelect")` and my .js looks like this

```
values: Ember.computed('user' function() {
  const values = [];
  this.get('user.listOfThings').forEach(value => {
    values.push(value.get('name'));
  });
  return values;
}),
```

with a similar thing for the options array.

My problem is that the strings that are in `value.get('name')` are not displayed. It is definitely picking up the array because the right number of elements appear in the combobox but they are just empty div elements. The variable `values` ends up being an array of strings which seems to work normally everywhere else. Does someone know something I don't? I cant find anything in the [docs](https://netguru.github.io/ember-select-guru/#multiple) or in the [source code](https://github.com/netguru/ember-select-guru/tree/master/app/components) to help me.

I would also be open to using something else that behaves the same way. The is an example of how it should look in the [docs](https://netguru.github.io/ember-select-guru/#multiple).

Comment: Doesn't the dependency need to read `user.listofThings.@each.name`?

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer. I looked at the source for the docs page and found that the component seems to be looking for an array of objects which have a name field. Luckily enough my list of things already had a name attribute and I just needed to call .toArray(). Code looked like this:

```
values: Ember.computed('user', function() {
  return this.get('user.listOfThings').toArray();
}
```

However in a more general case you would need to use:

```
values: Ember.computed('user', function() {
  var values = [];
  this.get('user.listOfThings').forEach(value => {
    values.push({ name: value.get('attributeYouWant'), other: other });
  };
  return values;
}
```

This is somewhat useful because an array of strings isn't all that functional but it maybe should be a little clearer than having to look at source code for a web page in the dev tools of your browser.